Multiple p values in statplot made for chi-square test
I used ggstatplot package for plotting chi-square test results.
ggbarstats(mtcars, x = vs, y = cyl)

I understand p value mentioned in the first line is pvalue for chi-square test. What does the p value indicates on each bars in the plot. There are three p values for each plot.


See the explanation and the example in the docs: ... were significantly different than 50% as indicated by a goodness of fit test, i.e. the p-value for each bar refers to whether the proportions are significantly different from a uniform distribution.
